# Matrix elements addition with this way

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, addition

I wrote this code to add elements with this way my problem is that i want to apply it with larger matrix

```
zz=[[1,2],[3,4]]
for i in range(len(zz[0])):
    x=zz[0][i]
    for i in range(len(zz[1])):
        xx=x+zz[1][i]
        print(xx)
```

The output will be:

```
z[0][0]+z[1][0]
z[0][0]+z[1][1]
z[0][1]+z[1][0]
z[0][0]+z[1][1]
```

Comment: So you want all sums of combinations of elements in your sublists? Can you give some more concrete examples of what the outputs would be for a larger matrix?

Comment: The output i want is:                                       1+3   1+4   2+3   2+4 and so on with larger matrices is that clear ?

Comment: It is clear what you want for this case. What would you want for the case [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use recursion for this:

```
def sum_combinations(matrix):
    head, *tail = matrix
    if not tail:  # we reached the last row
        yield from head
        return
    for number in head:
        for other in sum_combinations(tail):
            yield number + other
```

This should work for any size of matrix.

Usage:

```
for sum_ in sum_combinations(zz):
    print(sum_)
```